# How to generate random numbers up to 100 in an array size of 10

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I have to create an array size of 10 and generate random numbers from 0 to 100 including 0 and excluding 100.  When I write the code it keeps giving me an error of:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 59
    at BillyLancasterHw6.printArray(BillyLancasterHw6.java:23)
    at BillyLancasterHw6.main(BillyLancasterHw6.java:13)**

Here is the code I am using.

```
public class BillyLancasterHw6 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //int N = 10;
    double[] list = new double[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      double randomNumber = (Math.random() * 100);
      list[i] = randomNumber;
  }
  printArray(list);
  //sort(list);
  //System.out.println();
  //printArray(list);       
  }

  public static void printArray(double[] list) {
    for(double u: list) {
      System.out.printf("%2.2f%s", list[(int) u], " ");
    }
  }
}
```

I am not understanding why I cannot generate random numbers up to 100 in an array of size 10.  Meaning that 10 numbers are randomly generated between 0 and 100.

Any suggestions would be great.  If you can reference where in the documentation I can find the answers as well.  I am new to programming and am having trouble with this.

Comment: -1 The chance to get a 100 is smaller than the chance to get a 99. This is not realy random.

Answer (score 5):

Your enhanced `for` loop has already done the job of extracting the random number for you out of the list; just print it.  There's no need to go back to the list.

```
System.out.printf("%2.2f%s", u, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit rusty on my java but:

```
for(double u: list) {
  System.out.printf("%2.2f%s", list[(int) u], " ");
}
```

looks suspicious. What about this:

```
for(double u: list) {
  System.out.printf("%2.2f%s", u, " ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not getting your question but see if the code below work's. I don't understand why your using double

```
public class BillyLancasterHw6 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int[] randomNumber = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < randomNumber.length; i++)
    {
      randomNumber[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

      System.out.print(randomNumber[i]+" , ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, he did say random _numbers_, not integers :)

Comment: Well maybe he should have stated real numbers to clarify the situation, maybe the same code will work for doubles as he seems to be trunking the output with the %.2f Thanks for the constructive criticism

Comment: I am a beginning programming student and this was an assignment I was having issues make work. The instructor wanted a double.

Comment: Have you sorted this now or are you still at a loss ?